# module imported by top level script not seen by custom modules

Tags: python, import, module

I have a top level script (in top level directory) that imports a custom module 'reporting' (in a subdirectory)

when the script calls a function from that module that uses re.match I encountered an import problem, when I launch it I have the error :

```
    111         if sys.argv[i] in valid_options:
    112             current_option_type = valid_options[sys.argv[i]];
--> 113             if (re.match(r'\barg\b',current_option_type)):
```

'NameError: name 're' is not defined'`

indeed, when I check my imported modules, I end up with

`In [12]: set(sys.modules)&set(globals())
Out[12]: {'datetime', 'os', 'sys'}`

In order to make it work I decide to import another module which, itself, imports re (and is located in a sub directory):

```
import ip_interface
```

I call my function and ends up with the same error, when I check, I have:

`In [14]: set(sys.modules)&set(globals())
Out[14]: {'datetime', 'ip_interface', 'os', 'sys'}`

So I change my way of importing my ip_interface module and do :

```
from ip_interface.ip_interface import *
```

I check my imported modules :

`In [16]: set(sys.modules)&set(globals())
Out[16]:
{'datetime',
 'ip_interface',
 'knxnet',
 'os',
 're',              ===> I got it !
 'socket',
 'subprocess',
 'sys'}`

Then I launch my script and end up with:

```
    111         if sys.argv[i] in valid_options:
    112             current_option_type = valid_options[sys.argv[i]];
--> 113             if (re.match(r'\barg\b',current_option_type)):
```

NameError: name 're' is not defined

I wonder out what is wrong as I can see 're' module as imported.

When I import it directly in my module, it finally works. 
Isn't it possible to 'share' an import and avoid doing in all the sub modules requiring it ?

Comment: Theoricaly that should work. Why you do from ip_interface.ip_interface import * instead from ip_interface import *?

Comment: I have a package named ip_interface that contains ip_interface.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid this `NameError` you have to do `import re` in your main module, otherwise the name `re` will not be known there. It is not enough to do an `import re` in an imported module, because that is a different namespace.

The fact that it shows up in `sys.modules` only means that it has been imported somewhere. But to see it in your module's namespace, you need to do `import re` in that module.

Comment: It's strange. I have tested with a dummy.py which import re: In [1]: from dummy import *

In [2]: import sys

In [3]: set(sys.modules)&set(globals())
Out[3]: {'__builtin__', 're', 'sys'}

Comment: `from dummy import *` imports every name from `dummy` in your namespace. So also the `re` module that was imported in `dummy`.

Comment: B.t.w., using `from xxx import *` is usually not recommended, because you pollute your own namespace with all names that are defined in `xxx`.

Comment: I do the following imports in my top module: import re, 
from ip_interface.ip_interface import * and from reporting.reporting import *, I start a new python shell (to be sure) but it gives me the same message... Is it possible to know which modules are loaded for a namespace ?

Comment: Maybe. I would have to think about that. But I think that is a red herring. The rule to follow is: if you use a construct like `x.y`, you need to ensure that `x` is known in your *current* namespace. If `x` is a module from the standard library, the canonical way to do that is `import x`.

Comment: so each module has its own namespace with its own imports but imports cannot be shared between namespaces ... thanks for your explanation :)